# select query in hibernate with where clause

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have class Login which has `userId`, `username` and `password`.

For a user to login I am checking `username` and `password` and geting `userId`.
If `userId` is not zero then it will lead to home page. I am trying to do this in hibernate. But my query is not working

```
public int userLogin(Login login)
        throws MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException, SQLException,
        Exception {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    int userId = 0;

    try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            String hql = "Select log.userId from Login log where log.userName=:userName 
            and log.password=:password";      
            System.out.println(hql);
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            query.setParameter(":userName", login.getUserName());
            query.setParameter(":password", login.getPassword());
            List result = query.list();

            System.out.println("resultset:"+result);

            Iterator iterator = result.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                userId = (int) iterator.next();


        }
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (session.getTransaction() != null) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
```

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty, No need of ":" :)

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? Or just an empty result list? Please post more details about _"my query is not working"_.

Comment: So,what error you are facing? any exception..

Comment: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [:userName]
 at org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterDescriptor(ParameterMetadata.java:101)
 at org.hibernate.engine.query.ParameterMetadata.getNamedParameterExpectedType(ParameterMetadata.java:107)
 at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractQueryImpl.determineType(AbstractQueryImpl.java:460)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) You are using HQL, so you need to understand that you can't give column names which are in database in projections of HQL query

```
 String hql = "select user_id from login where user_name= :username and  
            password= :password";
```

Here in your Login class you don't have field as `user_id` and you gave `user_id` into projections.
HQL maps class with database, hence Login class will login table and userId field will be user_id column in database.And what you wrote is plain SQL query not HQL query.

Please use this HQL query.

```
String hql="Select log.userId from Login log where log.username=:username and log.password=:password"
```

Here log is alias name like we do in plain Java.

```
Login log=new Login()
log.userId
```

Answer (score 5):

Try not use colon while setting the param.

```
query.setParameter("userName", login.getUserName());
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, the other answer is long winded, confusing, beside the point, etc.