# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that name [xxx] did not exist

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter with that name [xxx] did not exist

I'm using `Spring-data-jpa` + `hibernate`

```
String login = "AdanaKebap";
String userQuery = "select * from user where username like '%:login%'"; // not working
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(userQuery);
query.setParameter("login", login);
List<Object[]> userObjects = query.getResultList();
```

I'd try

```
String userQuery = "select * from user where username like '%?%'"; // not working
query.setParameter("1", login);

String userQuery = "select * from user where username like '%?1%'"; // not working
query.setParameter("1", login);

String userQuery = "select * from user where username like ':login'"; // not working
query.setParameter("login", login);

String userQuery = "select * from user where username like :login "; // not working
query.setParameter("login", login);

String userQuery = "select * from user where username = :login "; // working, but i don't need this
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27034359/select-query-in-hibernate-with-where-clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `CONCAT`, to concat `%` and the value passed to the query, so try :

```
String userQuery = "select * from user where username like CONCAT('%', ?1, '%')";
//...
query.setParameter(1, login); // note here you have to use the index of placeholder
```

or

```
String userQuery = "select * from user where username like CONCAT('%', :login, '%')'";
//...
query.setParameter("login", login);
```